# widgets_on_pages not working

Tags: wordpress

Hello i'm using [widgets_on_pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-on-pages/) to place widgets on pages, i installed it and added a widget to the panel in my admin section, then i added `[widgets_on_pages id=2]` ("its the 2nd sidebar and it said i should add this") into my html on the place where the widget should appear but it only shows the code i added in pure text, nothing else happens, anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then the following applies... if not, apologies.

You should not need to do it this way. It seems that Vincent, you are trying to add the shortcode into a theme php file... this is incorrect and the shortcode is for adding into the page/post content by the post/page editor.

To add a Widgets on Pages sidebar to a template then v 0.0.7  (I believe) has built in template tags (see [link text](http://gingerbreaddesign.co.uk/2010/08/17/widgets-on-pages-0-0-7/)). This should allow you to add the following I think

```
<?php widgets_on_template("2"); ?>
```

Comment: I'm gonna have to accept this answer instead cause it seems like the correct one. Ty very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[widgets_on_pages id=2]'] ?>
```